Powerpoint vba macro to play and pause embedded video in slide
I am trying to write a macro which has following features for an embedded video in active slide

the macro plays the video if the video is paused
the macro pauses the video if the video is playing
When the video reaches end, on executing the macro, it should move to next slide.

I came across an old article which describes similar function https://www.skphub.com/2013/control-media-player.htm  However, i am not able to make the code work.
I have slightly modified the code, the code is present below.

Option Explicit
Private shapeId As Integer
Private mediaPlayer As Player
Function MediaPlayerRefInSlideShowWindow(Index As Long) As Boolean
    shapeId = GetMediaShapeId(Index)
    If shapeId > 0 Then
        Set mediaPlayer = SlideShowWindows(1).View.Player(shapeId)
        MediaPlayerRefInSlideShowWindow = True
          mediaPlayer.Play
    Else
        MsgBox "No media shape found on the slide."
    End If
End Function

Function GetMediaShapeId(Index As Long) As Long
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(Index).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoMedia Then
            GetMediaShapeId = shp.Id
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next shp
    GetMediaShapeId = -1
End Function

Sub PlayMediaInSlideShow()
If MediaPlayerRefInSlideShowWindow(SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition) Then
    If mediaPlayer.State = 1  Then
        mediaPlayer.Play
    End If
 If mediaPlayer.State = 0  Then
        mediaPlayer.Pause
    End If
If mediaPlayer.State =2   Then
        SlideShowWindows(1).View.Next
    End If
End If
End Sub



The problem i face here is that the mediaplayer.state returns only o i.e. media is playing and it never resturns 1 or 2. Moroever, the video when ends it automatically shifts to frame 1 eventhough rewind feature is unselected in checkbox.
Please i need help to make the code run, i am not an expert in VBA.
Thanks for your help

Please read How do I format my code blocks?, particularly the section about code fences. Manually adding '''''''code starts''''''' is unnecessary. Also, please try to trim some of the whitespace in your post; it requires quite a bit of scrolling as-is.
